# type definition in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, definition

From [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) I found this code:

```
type Arrayish<T> = {
  length: number;
  [x: number]: T;
};
```

Can anybody help me find out what is the meaning of [x: number]: T?

Answer (score 0):

It is specifying the type of the index signature, meaning that Arrayish can take on keys of type `number`, mapping to values of type `T`.

e.g. you can have:

```
const myArray: Arrayish<string> = {
  length: 2,
  1: "cat",
  2: "dog"
}
```

check out: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types